# How does server-side rendering improve perceived performance compared to client-side rendering?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

If we get HTML data from server side, I think it will get max time than json data, so how can server side rendering improve our web app performance?

please explain this in simple way on reactJS flow and structure. according to react.js server side rendering better or not?

What is the flow and structure of server-side rendering in React.js?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of server-side rendering in React.js applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server rendering, like in React, pre-generates content on the server. This means users see a usable page faster, even before JavaScript loads. It's a balance: quicker start vs. more server work. Good for SEO and slower connections. Decide based on your app's needs.

In React, SSR pre-renders components on the server, so the user gets a usable page faster. Once JavaScript loads, React takes over for interactivity. It's a trade-off: quicker initial load vs. more work on the server. SSR is beneficial for SEO and users on slow connections.

Deciding if SSR is 'better' depends on your app's needs. It's powerful for first-load speed and SEO but may add complexity. Evaluate based on your user base and app requirements.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

In ReactJS, server-side rendering (SSR) is generally faster than client-side rendering (CSR) for the initial page load. This is because with SSR, the server generates the complete HTML content along with the initial data, and sends it to the client. As a result, the client receives a fully-rendered page and can display it immediately to the user.

On the other hand, with client-side rendering, the initial page load is slower because the client needs to download the JavaScript bundle and execute it to render the content.

However, after the initial load, CSR can provide a smoother user experience as it allows for faster page transitions and interactions. SSR can be beneficial for SEO purposes and better initial load performance, but CSR can improve user experience once the initial page is loaded.

We can use a combination of both techniques to strike a balance between initial load performance and overall user experience. NextJs, which is a React Framework, allows to do it via various [rendering options](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering).

Answer (score 1):

Server-side rendering is faster than client-side rendering because the server renders the page on the server and sends the fully rendered HTML page to the client, while client-side rendering requires the client to download and execute JavaScript before the page can be rendered. This can take a few seconds, which can be a significant delay for users with slow internet connections.

In ReactJS, SSR can be implemented using a library like Next.js or Gatsby. These libraries allow you to render your React pages on the server and send the rendered HTML to the client, which can significantly improve page load time and SEO.